# Packaging custom classes in Laravel 5

Tags: php, class, laravel-5, package

I'm a newbie to Laravel framework. I have created a custom class called *UploadUtils.php* and placed it inside the **App\Classes**.

```
<?php

namespace App\Classes;

class UploadVideoUtils{
    public static function checking(){
        echo "FRom the func";
    }
}
```

I was able to use that class in my controller like below code.

```
use App\Classes\UploadVideoUtils;

class Test extends Controller{

public function testing(){
        echo "Testing ";

        $some1 = new UploadVideoUtils();
        $some1->checking();

        echo " done ";
     }
}
```

I don't want to put all of classes under **App\Classes**. Instead I want to package them and I want to maintain nice code base. 
So, I created a new folder like **App\Classes\Common** and put my *UploadUtils.php* class and try to call it from the controller. But it magically copy the *UploadUtils.php* file in **App\Classes**. And it doesn't use the file in **App\Classes\Common**.

How to have proper packaging *(Directory structure)* for my custom classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have deleted the file in `App\Classes`. Then in your controller use `App\Classes\Common\UploadUtils`.
Then run `composer dumpautoload` to regenerate the autoloader.